# Употребление слова «предлежащий» вместо «настоящий»

Tags: грамотная-речь, стилистика, выбор-слов, синонимы

Могу ли я использовать слово «предлежащий» вместо «настоящий» в словосочетании «настоящий документ» или «настоящий акт», т. е. «данный документ»?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, употребление слова «предлежащий» вместо «настоящий» в приведенных вами контекстах некорректно.

«Предлежащий» слово устаревшее, значащее «лежащий перед кем-чем-либо» или «предстоящий». В наше время принято говорить «данный *или* настоящий документ, акт и т. п.».

Comment: "Данный" - менее точное слово, чем "настоящий": оно может относиться к ранее упомянутому другому документу.

Comment: @Alex_ander да, вы правы. Впрочем, есть контексты, в которых они взаимозаменяемы.